# What is the difference between Selenium core extensions and Selenium IDE extensions?

Tags: selenium, ide

I know that for using my js file I must use Selenium Core extension but I cannot understand what Selenium IDE Extension field is for?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium extensions provide a way to add more functionality/feature to Selenium as per your requirements. This is also known as Selenium User-Extensions and Selenium Custom-Extensions.

The concept is pretty simple, extend Selenium by adding your own **actions**, **assertions** and **locator-strategies**. Add JavaScript methods to the Selenium object prototype and the PageBot object prototype. On startup, Selenium will automatically look through methods on these prototypes, using name patterns to recognize which ones are actions, assertions and locators.

User-Extensions can be used with Selenium IDE (see [this](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/08_user_extensions.jsp#using-user-extensions-with-selenium-ide)) and Selenium RC (see [this](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/08_user_extensions.jsp#using-user-extensions-with-selenium-rc)).

Do not get confused with different names. Same concept is getting used at different places, differently.

Answer (score 0):

"Selenium IDE Extensions" is mainly used to extend the recording behavior of Selenium IDE.

**To use the extensions**

1. Copy the extension code into a new .js file. You can place it
   anywhere on your disk.
2. Open Options - Options... in the menu bar.
3. Choose the saved file in "Selenium IDE extensions" field and click OK.
4. Restart Selenium IDE by closing the window and opening it again.

**Example**

By default, Selenium IDE only records click events on certain types of elements (e.g. , , ...).
You can record any click events occured in a page by putting the following code as Selenium IDE extension.

```
Recorder.removeEventHandler('clickLocator');
Recorder.addEventHandler('clickLocator', 'click', function(event) {
    if (event.button == 0) {
        this.clickLocator = this.findLocator(event.target);
    }
}, { capture: true });
```